# Not understanding Null Pointer Exception in my code (java)

Tags: java

I know what a Null Pointer exception is, but i dont understand why I'm getting it.

Here is the line it throws the error:

```
IUserAction pinResponse = ATM.getUserResponse("Please enter your 4-digit PIN.",    ActionType.STRING);
```

IUserAction is a public Interface class and ActionType a enum.

It's strange because I was given code to add to, and this line was given to me, and I assumed that it was supposed to work, while I am new to Java, I'm not new to object oriented programming, so I'm not sure why this is not working.

here's more of the code:

```
package com.atm;

import com.atm.IUserAction.ActionType;

/**
 * The ATM implementation class.
 * 
 * @author mshields
 * 
 */
public class AtmImpl {

    private static final IAtmHelper ATM = AtmUtils.getAtmHelper();

    /**
     * This method is invoked when a bank card is inserted into the ATM. The card
     * is ejected immediately upon completion of this method, which represents the
     * user's ATM session.
     * 
     * @param args
     *          the bank card number is the only argument.
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        IUserAction pinResponse = ATM.getUserResponse("Please enter your 4-digit PIN.", ActionType.STRING);

        if (ActionType.STRING.equals(pinResponse.getActionType())
                && ATM.verifyPIN(args[0], pinResponse.getStringEntry())) 
        {
            // todo: ...
```

heres the beginning to IUserAction

```
package com.atm;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * Interface that defines a user action at the ATM.
 * 
 * @author mshields
 * 
 */
public interface IUserAction {

    public enum ActionType {
        /**
         * Indicates that the user typed a series of characters or digits (for
         * example, a PIN).
         */
        STRING,
```

and ATM

```
package com.atm;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

import com.atm.IUserAction.ActionType;

/**
 * Interface that defines ATM utility methods.
 * 
 * @author mshields
 * 
 */
public interface IAtmHelper {
```

Comment: ATM is null. Where do you initialize it?

Comment: What about `ATM`, is that a Class or instance?

Comment: post the whole class with it..

Comment: @Kon - it can be statc method of ATM

Comment: Yes it CAN be a static method of ATM, BUT we can't know for sure.

Comment: If `ActionType` really is an enum, a NPE in this line can only come from `ATM` being null.

Comment: Can you show the ATM's class and it's method getUserResponse?

Comment: public IUserAction getUserResponse(String argMessage,
   ActionType... argValidActionTypes);

Comment: Check `AtmUtils.getAtmHelper()` if it can return `null`.

Comment: it returns null. not sure what you mean to check if it can

Comment: If it returns null, it is clear that ATM is null as well. This is your problem then. You need a valid instance of ATM to call methods on it.

Comment: but ATM is a IAtmHelper, which is a interface, not a class, hence i dont understand how to create an instance of it, because from what I learned, you can have instances of interfaces.

Comment: You need to create an instance of a class that implements `IAtmHelper`.